# Can I move on to the next level (test) of invariance when my fit gets better?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, group-differences, invariance, scale-invariance

I am running a group invariance test.
The data consists of data from students from grades 5 and 6 for one school (School A)
and only from grade 5 in another school (School B).

I have already run group invariance tests for Grade 5(A) and Grade 5(B) and it holds for
partial strong invariance.
I have also run group invariance for Grade 5(A) and Grade 6(A) and full strong invariance holds.

Now I am running Grade 5(AB) and Grade 6(A)and encountering an interesting phenomenon.
The fit for Configural invariance is not bad but metric invariance gives be much better RMSEA fit (RMSEA decreases by half).

I am speculating that because Grade5(A) and Grade6(A) have closer measures to one another (better invariance), when loadings are fixed for both groups, the model shows better fit.

So my question is,

1. Does my thinking of why fit becomes better for metric invariance make sense?
2. If I am comparing models using delta-CFI and RMSEA (restricted vs non-restricted model), do I still need to modify the restricted model to match the less better model?
   Or can I just move on to testing scalar invariance?

Thank you everyone in advance for your help.